# R: Categorising Date intervals and adding rows for between data intervals

Tags: r

I have a data-set of course enrollments over time, as indicated by a start_date and end_date for ~50,000 ids. I am interested in capturing both periods of enrollment and non-enrollment for this group over a specific time frame, specifically from '2001-06-01' to '2015-01-01' even though the data goes back earlier. I am interested in creating rows for each id that captures the date intervals for these periods of enrollment/non-enrollment, and creating an additional variable that categorizes these periods;  'prior to enrollment', 'enrolled', 'between enrollment', 'never enrolled'.

To clarify;

Some example data

```
id = c(1,3,3,3,5,5)
entry_date = c(NA, '1996-05-09', '2005-12-12', '2013-12-19', '2011-11-05','2012-12-10')
exit_date = c(NA, '2005-12-10', '2008-12-10', '2016-01-01', '2016-09-01', '2013-02-20')
test
```

```
id entry_date  exit_date
 1      NA       NA
 3 1996-05-09 2005-12-10
 3 2005-12-12 2008-12-10
 3 2013-12-19 2016-01-01
 5 2011-11-05 2012-09-01
 5 2012-12-10 2013-02-20
```

My intended output would be;

```
id entry_date  exit_date  category
 1 2001-06-01 2016-01-01  Never enrolled
 3 2001-06-01 2005-12-10  Enrolled
 3 2005-12-10 2005-12-12  Between enrollment
 3 2005-12-12 2008-12-10  Enrolled
 3 2008-12-10 2013-12-19  Between enrollment
 3 2013-12-19 2016-01-01  Enrolled
 5 2001-06-01 2011-11-05  Prior to enrollment
 5 2011-11-05 2012-09-01  Enrolled
 5 2012-09-01 2012-12-10  Between enrollment
 5 2012-12-10 2013-02-20  Enrolled
 5 2013-02-20 2016-01-01  Between enrollment
```

Any help in how to achieve something like this would be really appreciated!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what classifies someone into the three groups "Never enrolled", "Enrolled" and "Between enrollment". Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: There was a mistake in one of the dates that probably made this more confusing that I've corrected, but basically if the period of study is 01-06-2001 up to 01-06-2016 and a period of enrollment is the interval between the entry date and exit date in the data, I would like to create a row that indicates between enrollment, so the interval between the exit date and the next following entry date for that individual (if there is one). Hope the helps?